# Can someone give me a natural language example of the following in-equivalence?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$$\forall x \exists y (F(x) \leftrightarrow K(x,y)) \not\equiv \forall x (F(x) \leftrightarrow \exists y K(x,y)) $$

The statement on the right is not same as the statement on the left and I understand it by finding counter models to the equivalence. But can some one give me a natural language example where this in-equivalence is more intuitive ?

For counter model:

https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%80x%E2%88%83y(Fx%20%E2%86%94%20Kxy)%20%20%E2%86%92%20%E2%88%80x%20(Fx%20%E2%86%94%20%E2%88%83yKxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give an example where the left-hand part is true, but the right-hand part isn't. Suppose a club needs face ID. For each person $x$, there is a face $y$ such that that person may enter the club ($F(x)$) iff their ID has that face on it ($K(x,\,y)$); this is, of course, their own face. On the other hand, it's not true that each person can enter iff *some* face appears on their ID; it has to be *their* face.

Comment: F(x) --> 'x' can enter the club. K(x,y) --> 'x 's ' has a face id 'y' on it. LHS : forall people 'x' there exists at least one face id y such that 'x' can enter the club iff x's face id is y. RHS: For all people 'x' they can enter the club iff there exists atleast one one face id 'y' such that x's face id is 'y'. I dont understand any of the statement to be imposing "their own face"

Comment: @SagarM $K(x,\,y)$ means "$x$ presents an ID with $y$'s face on it". The first statement claims for each a person there's a face such that they can enter iff that face is on the ID they show. The second statement claims a person can enter iff their ID isn't faceless.